# How seprate values from text box text

Tags: vb.net, text, extract

I have text box in which i have taken number like this 01234567810121300050 this number read and captured from barcode and inserted into a text box and this is divided into three parts
A-Ticket No, B-date, C-Amount Ticket No-0123456789, Date=101213, amuunt=00050 how can seprate this number into three diffrent textboxes i.e. TextboxA=0123456789, TextboxB=10-12-2013 and TextboxC=Rs.50
kindly provide vb.net code for windows application

Any one help me in this context I shall be greatfull to you

Thanks and Regard

Comment: you can Use Substring

Comment: is number of digits in ticket number fixed?

Comment: Let me know whether number of digits in Ticket No is fixed or not....and Date format is always like you given.

Comment: yes ticket number is fixed at nine digit 999999999 and date 120113 here 12 is date 01 is month and 13 is year. kindly send codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is assuming that the length of TicketNo is fixed (9)

```
Dim s = "01234567810121300050"
Dim TicketNo = CInt(s.Substring(0, 9))
Dim DateValue = Date.ParseExact(s.Substring(9, 6), "ddMMyy", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim AmountTicket = CInt(s.Substring(15))
```

Comment: nice job get problem is resovled

Comment: date format ddmmyy is not working properly given date mmddyy as per system date kindly help me

Comment: im not understand. the Data format its variable? dependent wat?

Comment: TextBox3.Text = Date.ParseExact(s.Substring(9, 6), "ddMMyy", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) in these codes dates are showing in mm/dd/yy while i need dd/mm/yy showing this "12/30/2013" instead 30/12/2013

Comment: add at end of line: `.ToString("dd/MM/yy")`

Comment: or replace line with: `TextBox3.Text = String.Join("/", {s.Substring(9, 2), s.Substring(11, 2), s.Substring(13.2)})
`

Comment: String.Join("/", {s.Substring(9, 2) + s.Substring(11, 2) + s.Substring(13, 0)}) in this line its saying end expected there is somewehre syntex missing kindly help

Comment: `String.Join("/", {s.Substring(9, 2) + s.Substring(11, 2) + s.Substring(13, 2)})` and plz, ACCEPT MY ANNSWER...

Comment: i tried this ealier but { giving message expression expected and at closing tiem } messaging end of statement expected. How can i accept your answer i m not finding any button here. you codes are very much excellent. may allah full fill your all desire.